# Cannot read property 'removeCls' of null for tagfield in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'm upgrading my `ExtJs` application `form 4 to 5.1` . Initially I was using `boxselect` component from `UX`, but in `ExtJS 5.1` this component come in core Ext directory. So I removed boxselect and replaced with tagfield as said in up gradation guide. But after doing this I start getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCls' of null.

If I rename tagfield with combo it work without any error.

I am changing `xtype : ''` only, nothing else, don't know exactly what else I missing in upgrading `boxselect to tagfield in extjs 5` ?

Edit -:
After debuging more I found problem in `toggleInvalidCls()` method from `Ext.form.field.Text`..Please find code bellow,

```
toggleInvalidCls: function(hasError) {
    var method = hasError ? 'addCls' : 'removeCls';
    this.callParent();
    this.triggerWrap[method](this.triggerWrapInvalidCls);//getting error here
    this.inputWrap[method](this.inputWrapInvalidCls);
},
```

this.triggerWrap object coming null for tagfield...any reason ?
Brwoser console also showing warning `XTemplate evaluation exception: wrapperStyle is not defined` before throwing error of removeCls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got problem with my combo override.Just removed existing combo override, now able to show tagfield.

I have forgot that I have combo override in my application.

**Remember** - If you are using `tagifled` with your existing combo override consider it while upgrading `extjs 5` with tagfield.